# Creating AWS route53 module using Terraform with for_each and data lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, alias, amazon-route53

I am fairly new to terraform and trying to learn about using the for_each argument in order to write a scalable route53 module. Idea is to write a root route53 record module which can be used to create multiple alias records in a private hosted zone with the ability to add weighted routing if required for blue / green deployments.

The repo is setup to have root aws modules, and then two layers of child modules below the root modules to define resources per environment:

```
-aws
--modules

---route53
----main.tf
----variables.tf
----locals.tf
----data.tf

---s3
----main.tf
----variables.tf
----locals.tf
----data.tf

...etc (other aws root modules)

--modules.tf (pulls code using root modules as the source)
--variables.tf
--locals.tf
--data.tf

--environment (specify aws tfvars for each environment)
---dev.tfvars
---test.tfvars
---prod.tfvars
```

**I have written the root module as follows:**

Main.tf

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "private_alias_record" {
  name     = var.name
  zone_id  = data.aws_route53_zone.private.zone_id
  type     = var.type


  alias {
    name    = var.alias_name
    zone_id = var.alias_zone_id
  }

  dynamic "weighted_routing_policy" {
    for_each = each.value.weight == null ? [] : [each.value.weight]

    content {
      weight = weighted_routing_policy.value
    }
  }
  
  set_identifier = var.set_identifer
```

**Then first child layer to call the root module:**

modules.tf

```
#this module creates a route53 weighted record that points to an NLB

module "route53-private-alias-record" {
  source = "./modules/route53"
  for_each = var.records

  name            = each.value.name
  type            = each.value.type
  alias_name      = data.aws_lb.eks_nlb.dns_name
  alias_zone_id   = data.aws_lb.eks_nlb.zone_id
  weight          = each.value.weight
  set_identifier  = each.key
```

variables.tf

```
variable "records" {
description = "Specifies values for route53 private alias records"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    type             = string
    alias            = map(string)
    weight           = number
    cluster_name     = string
    nlb_tag = string
  }))
  }
}
```

data.tf

This looks up the NLB using tags (As NLB created via kubernetes not AWS directly)

```
data "aws_lb" "eks_nlb" {
  for_each = var.records
  tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/${each.value.cluster_name}" = "owned"
    "kubernetes.io/service-name"               = each.value.nlb_tag
  }
}
```

**dev environment tfvars**

```
  records = {
    blue = {
      name             = "application_1"
      type             = "A"
      cluster_name     = "cluster_a"
      weight           = "90"
      nlb_tag          = "ingress"
    }
    green = {
      name             = "application-1"
      type             = "A"
      cluster_name     = "cluster_b"
      weight           = "10"
      nlb_tag          = "ingress"
    }
  }
```

Questions I have are:

- Is it correct to use the for_each loop in the first child module rather than the root?
- Is the data type in variables.tf correct at map(object)?
- Is it correct having the set_identifier as the 'key'? This is a unique value in route53

And am I generally on the right track here with the use of for_each and the fact that there are 2 layers of child modules?

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors?